# Order of operator precedence in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, operator-precedence

I calculated the following in EXCEL

```
=EXP(-0.23998^2*0.02277)
```

which gave

```
1.001312
```

then I calculated it like this:

```
=EXP(-0.02277*0.23998^2)
```

which yielded:

```
0.99869
```

Which is the correct way I suppose. Why are the two not equal?

Comment: squaring a negative gives a positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the square of a negative number, you will have a positive.  Try this:

```
=EXP((-0.23998)^2*0.02277)
```

It should be the same as your first equation.  In your second equation you essentially did:

```
=EXP((-0.02277)*0.23998^2)
```